# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\tas\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php on line 152

Tags: php, sql-server

I've a codeigniter/php application running in **WAMP** and connected to **sql server database** using. When i tried to retrieve a long report from the system i'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\tas\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php on line 152
```

I've already increased **max_execution_time = 99999** in **php.ini** and also changet the value in **C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4\libraries\config.default.php the $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;** but still not working. What could be the reason, is there any thing I should change in **sqlsrv_driver.php** may be?

Comment: 1. I am pretty sure changing PhpMyadmin values in WAMP won't inpact SQL Server. 2. A query shouldn't be taking up 300 seconds of execution time in a web app. Maybe look into why this is taking so long first?

Comment: the query exacts thousands of rows of data from the data base and populates it in HTML table as a matrix with hundreds of columns. which means the table will have more than 100 columns and more than 20000 rows. the data is extract as a matrix by checking the combination of each row and column. That is why it takes more than 6 minutes to populate the table.

Comment: formatting and spelling mistakes

Comment: Do you really need to load all of that onto one page? What about pagination?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the timeout, preferably for that query only.

Comment: May be can you explain it to me in detail, how do i increase the time out?, as i mentioned above i've increased max_execution_time in php.ini and in config.default.php